# Seek bar for AVPlayer rounding off time to 10 seconds

Tags: iphone, ios, avplayer

I'm making a iPhone app and made a seek bar for a AVPlayer. I make it with a UISlider. AVPlayer works with online video and audio. But when I want make changes in the slider position to set the currentTime of the AVPlayer this value is rounded to the near top ten (for example put a value of 17 seconds, AVPlayer change it to 20 seconds.) The problem for online video. With online audio all okay.

Answer (score 1):

UISliders have properties called "minValue" and "maxValue" Once you know the length of the media you are about to play, make sure the resolution of these properties match the length of the media.

Comment: I have it set like that: durationTime = playerItem.duration.value / playerItem.duration.timescale;  startTime = 0.0;

Comment: But your problem is with the slider resolution, correct? Check and see what values are being passed along to the AVPlayer

Comment: -(IBAction) timeSliderValueChanged: (id) sender {
 CMTime newTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(timeSlider.value, 600); //here for example slider.value = 25
 [player seekToTime: newTime]; //set 25 sec for avplayer, but he start play with 30 sec.   Min/Max value correct.

}

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AVPlayer` `seek` with zero tolerance:

```
player.seek(to:
    CMTime(
        seconds: Double(value),
        preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    ),
    toleranceBefore: CMTime.zero,
    toleranceAfter: CMTime.zero
)
```